# News to Category/Section mapping DataSet

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, nlp, news

Is there a public dataset which has news articles to various sections/categories mapping?

For example:
Article 1 (title, text, etc, CATEGORY)
Article 2 (title, text, etc, CATEGORY)
Article 3 (title, text, etc, CATEGORY)
and so on.

Categories/sections should refer to commonly used names in news media such as sports, entertainment, science, tech, lifestyle, news, politics etc.

I did some search but couldn't find anything except [20newsgroup](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html) which is a very small dataset.